# A clang error:a strange use of xmmintrin.h and use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_emms'

Tags: android, c++

I'm trying to build a .so lib in android studio.when I write the abiFilters as  "x86","x86_64",**It can generate the lib of "x86","x86_64",and the system can run sussessfully**,so I think my cmakelists is right.But when write the abiFilters as 'arm64-v8a','armeabi', "armeabi-v7a","x86","x86_64",it can't generate the .so lib of "arm64-v8a",'armeabi', "armeabi-v7a".none of them can generate,I am wondering what's wrong with the system.

Here is my ***build.gradle***,and ***error informations***:

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "yuz.com.dpm_android"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                abiFilters 'arm64-v8a','armeabi', "armeabi-v7a","x86","x86_64"
                cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
            }
        }
        ndk{
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a','armeabi', "armeabi-v7a","x86","x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {

        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary320')

}
```

***Error Informations:***

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build D:\2018\DPM-Android\DPM-Android\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a --target DPM-lib}
[1/23] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/DPM-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/DPM/featpyramid.cpp.o
[2/23] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/DPM-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/DPM/fconv.cpp.o
[3/23] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/DPM-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/DPM/cvPermutate.cpp.o
[4/23] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/DPM-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/DPM/featpyramid2.cpp.o
[5/23] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/DPM-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/DPM/features.cpp.o
[6/23] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/DPM-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/DPM/loc_feat.cpp.o
FAILED: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  --target=aarch64-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Android/sdk3/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Android/sdk3/ndk-bundle/sysroot  -DDPM_lib_EXPORTS -I../../../../src/main/cpp/include -I../../../../src/main/cpp/DPM -isystem C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Android/sdk3/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Android/sdk3/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/arm64-v8a/include -isystem C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Android/sdk3/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -isystem C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Android/sdk3/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions -std=c++11 -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/DPM-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/DPM/fconv.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles\DPM-lib.dir\src\main\cpp\DPM\fconv.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/DPM-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/DPM/fconv.cpp.o -c D:\2018\DPM-Android\DPM-Android\app\src\main\cpp\DPM\fconv.cpp
In file included from D:\2018\DPM-Android\DPM-Android\app\src\main\cpp\DPM\fconv.cpp:3:
  In file included from C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include\xmmintrin.h:27:
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include\mmintrin.h:47:5: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_emms'; did you mean '__builtin_isless'?
      __builtin_ia32_emms();
      ^
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include\mmintrin.h:47:5: note: '__builtin_isless' declared here
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include\mmintrin.h:47:25: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 0
      __builtin_ia32_emms();
                          ^
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include\mmintrin.h:64:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si'
      return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);
                    ^
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include\mmintrin.h:81:12: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si'
      return __builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si((__v2si)__m, 0);
             ^
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include\mmintrin.h:143:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packsswb'
      return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packsswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                    ^
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include\mmintrin.h:173:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packssdw'
      return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packssdw((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                    ^
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include\mmintrin.h:203:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packuswb'
      return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packuswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                    ^
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include\mmintrin.h:230:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw'
      return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                    ^
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include\mmintrin.h:253:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd'
      return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                    ^
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include\mmintrin.h:274:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq'
      return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                    ^
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include\mmintrin.h:301:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw'
      return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                    ^
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include\mmintrin.h:324:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd'
      return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                    ^
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include\mmintrin.h:345:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckldq'
      return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckldq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                    ^
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include\mmintrin.h:366:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddb'
      return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                    ^
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include\mmintrin.h:387:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddw'
      return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                    ^
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include\mmintrin.h:408:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddd'
      return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddd((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                    ^
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include\mmintrin.h:430:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddsb'
      return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddsb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                    ^
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include\mmintrin.h:453:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddsw'
      return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddsw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                    ^
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\5.0.300080\include\mmintrin.h:475:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddusb'
      return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddusb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                    ^
  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
  20 errors generated.
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: Whatever you're trying to build is using x86 intrinsics. That won't work on Arm.

Comment: I deleted x86 intrinsics,only use 'arm64-v8a','armeabi', "armeabi-v7a",the problem also exists.I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: Without seeing your code nobody here will know what's wrong with it either. Consider a [mcve].

Comment: but i am still wondering that in AVD my program runs successfully but I can't generate arm's .so lib. And I don't think there's any logical problem with my C++ code.i'm confused